# Creating unfilled circle shapes using Farseer

Tags: farseer-physics-engine

I have a project idea that I need to create a sphere and use it's interior for collision detection. I can only find information in Farseer that creates a filled circle. Is there a way to do it with CircleShape or do I need to create the sphere using vertices? Or if anyone knows of another physics engine that can do this. Thanks

Comment: Farseer supports polygon shapes. Both circle and disk can be approximated with a polygon with certain number of sides. It means you will have to write some code to generate such a polygon however. You might need to split the resulting polygon into several parts. I believe you will have to deal with this in any physics engine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an chain shape which allows for 2 sided collision for the circle, but as far I know there is not a hollowed circle object.

http://www.box2d.org/manual.html